# Basic layout of appcelerator app

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I creating my first appcelerator app and looking for some info on whether something is possible, and if so is it easy to implement.

I'm using Titanium SDK 2.0.1.

I'm trying to create a layout similar to the Stream window in the Google+ app for Android:
 1: A large header (Can the navbar property of Ti.UI.createWindow be adjusted?)
 2: Two tabs under the header (Would like to be able to adjust height of them if possible? Are there alternatives to Ti.UI.createTabGroup if this is not possible?)

The main content I can figure out easily enough I reckon.

[image: Google+ layout I would like to replicate]

Any examples or links on how to achieve this layout would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that type of NavBar in Android using the native Ti.UI.Window properties, but you can just create your own NavBar using a view and stick to the top of the window. For the tabs, I'd look at http://www.tomaspersson.com/2012/03/20/titanium-viewpager-module-now-available/ - I'm not sure it will have all the options you need, but it is a good starting point. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tips Jeff, I'll look into those options.